# Edit User and relation in one form Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

I have two entities: User and UserDetails. Those entities have a one-to-one relation. I want to edit the User and User Details in the same form but somehow I can't get this to work.

I have the following error:

```
Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "App\Entity\UserDetails" given
```

This is my code

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    public $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    public $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    public $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserDetails", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $userDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Assignment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $assignments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->assignments = new ArrayCollection();
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }


    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt and argon2i algorithms don't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }


    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        if (!in_array('ROLE_USER', $roles)) {
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }
        return $roles;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function getUserDetails(): ?UserDetails
    {
        return $this->userDetails;
    }

    public function setUserDetails(UserDetails $userDetails): self
    {
        $this->userDetails = $userDetails;

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($this !== $userDetails->getUser()) {
            $userDetails->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Assignment[]
     */
    public function getAssignments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->assignments;
    }

    public function addAssignment(Assignment $assignment): self
    {
        if (!$this->assignments->contains($assignment)) {
            $this->assignments[] = $assignment;
            $assignment->addUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAssignment(Assignment $assignment): self
    {
        if ($this->assignments->contains($assignment)) {
            $this->assignments->removeElement($assignment);
            $assignment->removeUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

UserDetails entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserDetailsRepository")
 */
class UserDetails
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $street_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $zipcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $birthplace;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    public $birthdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $mobile_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $function;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userDetails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFunction()
    {
        return $this->function;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $function
     */
    public function setFunction($function)
    {
        $this->function = $function;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(?string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreetNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street_number;
    }

    public function setStreetNumber(?string $street_number): self
    {
        $this->street_number = $street_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZipcode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    public function setZipcode(?string $zipcode): self
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthplace(): ?string
    {
        return $this->birthplace;
    }

    public function setBirthplace(?string $birthplace): self
    {
        $this->birthplace = $birthplace;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function setBirthdate(?\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(?string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGender(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    public function setGender(?string $gender): self
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobileNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobile_number;
    }

    public function setMobileNumber(?string $mobile_number): self
    {
        $this->mobile_number = $mobile_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The method causing the error:

```
/**
     * @Route("/users/edit/{id}", name="editUsers")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, User $user, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder){
        $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);

        $form->add('userDetails', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => UserDetailsFormType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        ));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('success', 'User updated!');
            /* @var User $updated_user */
            $updated_user = $form->getData();


            if($updated_user->getPassword() != null) {
                $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($updated_user, $updated_user->getPassword());

                $updated_user->setPassword($password);
            }
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($updated_user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('users');
        }



        return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user
        ));
    }
```

I don't know if this is the right way to edit UserDetails and UserData at the same time. I'm open for other suggestion on how to do this! I hope someone can help me fix this problem!

Comment: Hello, did you tried to add just `$form->add('userDetails', UserDetailsFormType::class);`?

Comment: See the documentation on how to embed forms: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html effectively a `CollectionType` would be a series of multiple forms. e.g. `Entity::$tags = ArrayCollection|TagEntity[]` vs `Entity::$tag = TagEntity` So since your `User::$userDetails` is a `OneToOne` you would only need to embed the `UserDetailsFormType` not a collection of them.

Comment: @fyrye but he has a one-to-one relation here. He doesn't need an ArrayCollection here, also as he doesn't need a CollectionType.

Comment: @EugeneR that is what I said...

Comment: @fyrye yeap, sorry, doesn't see that you updated your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as mentioned by me and @fyrye in the comments: in case that `User` entity has a one-to-one relation to `UserDetails` entity - you just need to embed only a `UserDetailsFormType`, like that:

```
$form->add('userDetails', UserDetailsFormType::class);
```